# ActiveRecord: How to return counts of distinct votes?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My data model: Users, Votes, Items

Users can vote many times on an item

I want to return the total number of up and down votes for an item, *only counting the most recent one for a given user*

I was thinking something like selecting a distinct user_id and grouping by the value of the vote, but I'm not sure how I'd make the distinct pick up the most recent one..

I'd prefer to do this through the Rails 3 finder methods..

Comment: can you tell us more about your models, associations and the way you store the votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Soution 1.**

What about a mix of [**counter_cache**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) and, inside your **Item** model

```
has_many :up_votes, :class_name => "Vote", :conditions => {:condition_for_upvote => true}, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :down_votes, :class_name => "Vote", :conditions => {:condition_for_upvote => false}, :dependent => :destroy
```

You can order up and down votes by `created_at`.

**Soution 2.**

You can also use **[scopes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-default_scope)** crafting them to your specific ordering needs inside your **Vote** model and counting them after retrieving.

Comment: I didn't end up using exactly what you put (I didn't quite understand the :conditions bit) but I'm going to cache the counts on the items, which I think is the thrust of what you were saying with Solution 1